# Xamarin forms.Dynamically load a page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin forms.** 
How to dynamically load a content page from a string (xaml)? Not to create a lot of similar pages.

Comment: Do you want to create a xaml page dynamically?

Comment: eg

var page = new ContentPage() 
string xaml = ...
page.LoadFromXaml(xaml)
page.BindingContext = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Forms have Views, and Pages. Pages are a little different, but this sample has a class that loads UI from a XAML string as a ContentView. You can try loading from a Page as well.

- Just clone this repo
- Run the sample (Android/UWP have been tested
  well)
- Click on the Dynamic Rendering tab
- Hit Render (and have a play with the XAML)

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git