# Xamarin.Forms Load XAML View at Run time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically load a XAML file at Run time in Xamarin.Forms so it can then be displayed as a View / ContentPage.

I've already found some answers to this problem but they do not work anymore or the samples are deleted:

[Xamarin forms.Dynamically load a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255023/xamarin-forms-dynamically-load-a-page)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87727/load-xaml-dynamically-at-runtime

XAML example to load:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Examples.Views.TestView">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hello World!"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Are you looking to dynamically download these pages from a web site (or similar)?  Would the solution be simpler if you just used a WebView?

Comment: I'm downloading these from a web service so that I can edit them at run time. I'm not sure if a WebView would work in my case as I am using Bindings in my XAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the `LoadFromXaml` [extension method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml%7BTXaml%7D/p/TXaml/System.Type/).

Add this using:
`using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;`

And then inflate your page like this:

```
// TODO your XAML here
var xaml = "<ContentPage></ContentPage>";

var loadedXamlPage = new ContentPage();
loadedXamlPage.LoadFromXaml(xaml);
```

A sample repository can be found [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/LoadXamlSample).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick Answer with the solution.
I tried the same thing before but it did not work. But with your sample project I managed to find the error in my solution.

All I had to do was remove the Xamarin.Forms.Dynamic NuGet and update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet to the newest Version (2.5.0).
Now it works like a charm!